# Arduino with voice recognition module

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I have a hardware graduation project. I use in it voice `Recognition Module V3` to recognice voice.
I use `VoiceRecognitionV3` library to recognize voice in the code I found this :

```
myvr.begin(9600)
```

What dose this mean?

Comment: Please refer this http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/1570

Answer (score 0):

It is for initialize the serial connection with module at `9600bit/s`.